# Double entry table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to create a double entry table form according two models.

For now I'm able to create a simple table with the members of a communities
[image: normal table]

on the columns, I must add the informations of an other model, like this :
[image: double entry table]

My models :

**Community**

```
has_many :memberships
```

**Membership**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :community
```

**User**

```
has_many ::memberships
has_many :skills
```

**Skill**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :community
```

I there some gem existing to make a double entry table or is it easier to make it from scratch? if so, how can I begin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jay mentioned, you would benefit from a [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship, or maybe a [has_and_belongs_to_many relationship](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html); whether it's the actual solution we'll have to see:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class user < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :skill_users
    has_many :skills, through: :skill_users
end

#app/models/skill_user.rb
Class SkillUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :skill
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/skill.rb
Class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :skill_users
   has_many :users, through: :skill_users
end
```

This will allow you to associate each `user` (note that `members` are different than users) with specific skills without using double-entries in your tables

---

[**Relational**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)

The basis of what you're seeking can be found in Relational Databases

These work by storing data in single instances, and linking to other data through `foreign_keys`. These foreign keys are things such as `user_id` etc:

[image]

([more information here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr))

This means instead of populating the same data twice, it is correct to `reference` that data from other models, as required. This is where `join models` come in

---

**Join Model**

Join models allow you to "link" two pieces of data through a join model:

[image]

For you, it means storing your skills in its own model, and linking users with skills on a `join model` (I've called `skill_user.rb`). This means that you'll be able to call your user's skills like this:

```
@user.skills #-> goes through the join model
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you would benefit from a through relationship here.

Instead of referencing community directly from the skill table, you could do:

Skill

```
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :communities, :through => :user
```

On user, add:

```
 has_many :communities, :through => :memberships
```

Wouldn't this get the link between skill and community that you would like?